# Replace <italic> by <i> using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I have to transform element "italic" to "i", I found some of the solutions, but those solutions which i got from websites is working when i put that code in new xsl file, but if i put that in existing xsl it is not working.

Solution which i got :

```
<xsl:template match="italic">
    <I>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </I>
</xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

But I have the following xsl :

```
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:message>Inside root</xsl:message>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/root/ISSUES" />
</xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/root/ISSUES">
            some logic follows here( it might even internally call many templates)
    </xsl:template>
```

Can anyone tell me where to put the solution(code which is given first) in this xsl, please?

Thanks,
Shyam

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to ensure in your templates that processing of child nodes is kept up so you need to have `<xsl:apply-templates/>` (or `<xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>` if you also want to transform or copy attributes) in all your templates matching elements that can contain the `italic` elements. Thus you can of course write a template matching `root/ISSUES` but you need to ensure it keeps processing of children up by doing `<xsl:apply-templates/>`.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
<xsl:template match="italic">
    <I>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </I>
</xsl:template>
```

only. Processing of attributes and nodes would be handled by the rest of your code. The sample showed how to do the copying in the absence of any of your own logic. Your solution would then look like:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:message>Inside root</xsl:message>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/root/ISSUES" />
</xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/root/ISSUES">
            some logic follows here( it might even internally call many templates)
    </xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="italic">
    <I>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </I>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Sure! Give me the code that implements `some logic follows` and I will see what I can do.

Comment: it has another apply template section, this process recursively<xsl:apply-templates select="ISSUE" />                        Without seeing the xpath i have to replace or keep the <italic> as is. Is there any sloution.

Comment: I cannot comment on what is going wrong without seeing code. I know it is hard to get your head wrapped around the declarative nature of XSL. Right now, I suspect that your second match: `match="/root/ISSUES"`, is the issue.